# Maintaning the state of checkbox on scroll in android

Tags: android

**What i am doing:**

- I am trying to have checkbox in listview and trying to main state
  onscroll
- I tried with having boolean array state, but couldnt achieve it....so
  ihave come up with model class

---

---

**AdptSearchFilterCategories .java**

```
public class AdptSearchFilterCategories extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    List<ModelFilterCategories> mdlLst;

    public AdptSearchFilterCategories(Context context,
            List<ModelFilterCategories> mdlLst) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mdlLst = mdlLst;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mdlLst.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mdlLst.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        protected CheckBox chkBxCatId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ModelFilterCategories lclData = mdlLst.get(position);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_searchfilter_category, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.chkBxCatId = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBxCatId);
            viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                            mdlLst.get(getPosition).setCheckboxState(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                        }
                    });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setTag(position); // This line is important.

        viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setText(lclData.getCategoryName());
        // txtTitle.setId(Integer.valueOf(mapData.get("id")));
        viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setTag(lclData.getCategoryId());


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**ModelFilterCategories.java**

```
public class ModelFilterCategories {

    boolean checkboxState;
    String categoryName;
    String categoryId;

    public boolean isCheckboxState() {
        return checkboxState;
    }
    public void setCheckboxState(boolean checkboxState) {
        this.checkboxState = checkboxState;
    }
    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }
    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }
    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }
    public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

}
```

**Log:**

```
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421): Process: com.windhyaworks, PID: 9421
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.windhyaworks.adapters.AdptSearchFilterCategories$ViewHolder
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at com.windhyaworks.adapters.AdptSearchFilterCategories.getView(AdptSearchFilterCategories.java:69)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at com.navdrawer.SimpleSideDrawer.onMeasure(SimpleSideDrawer.java:443)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1942)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1132)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-16 17:00:16.000: E/AndroidRuntime(9421):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try this http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Comment: I used that blog to build this

Comment: can you try cleaning and rebuilding the project ?

Comment: @Blackbelt ...tried it, still the same error ! ... that blog is fine by not working for me ?

Comment: would you mind pointing out line 69 in `AdptSearchFilterCategories.java`

Comment: viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

Comment: it does make any sense. The snippet is correct. btw why are you doing ` viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setTag(lclData.getCategoryId());` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt .........Thats why im confused ! .... even though i delete the line you pointed ,,, still get the same bug

Comment: @Blackbelt .... I resolved it .... Have a look ... it was a sneaky error !(check my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

// getView

```
 if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.filter_list_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                        ((FilterListBean) itemList.get(getPosition)).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // had to use casting since get method was required,Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                    }
                });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        holder.checkBox.setTag(position); 
        holder.title.setText(menuList.getTitle());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked( menuList.getSelected());
```

//within constructor of adapter

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
        Log.v("count---", getCount() + "");
        itemChecked.add(i, false); // initializes all items value with false
    }
```

// adapter class variable list

```
  private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your operations are  not too expensive on ListView you can just comment that part, getView method will return a new row every time instead of getting it from cache.

```
 if (convertView == null)
```

your code will look like this

> ```
> final ModelFilterCategories lclData = mdlLst.get(position);
> ViewHolder viewHolder = null;           
> LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
> convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_searchfilter_category, null);
> viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
> viewHolder.chkBxCatId = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBxCatId);
> viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>            @Override
>          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
>                 int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the posion that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
>                             mdlLst.get(getPosition).setCheckboxState(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
>                         }
>                     });
>         viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setTag(position); // This line is important.
>         viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setText(lclData.getCategoryName());
>         // txtTitle.setId(Integer.valueOf(mapData.get("id")));
>         viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setTag(lclData.getCategoryId());
>         return convertView;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

### Sneaky Error

**I had adapter ::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chkBxCatId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

**I modified to::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chkBxCatId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it does any sense to me

Comment: @Blackbelt ...Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27506026/1083093 ...... though i rsolved this checkboxes below the list are checked.... i have made a new question