# Checkbox below the list are checked, if i check any checkboxes on top of the listview

Tags: android, checkbox

***What is Happening::***
Listview i am able to check the checkbox, when i scroll the list elements below the checkboxes down the list are are checked

***How can i resolve this !***

---

### {UPDATED CODE}

**AdptSearchFilterCategories.java**

```
 public class AdptSearchFilterCategories extends ArrayAdapter<ModelFilterCategories> {

    private Context context;
    List<ModelFilterCategories> mdlLst;


    public AdptSearchFilterCategories(Activity context, List<ModelFilterCategories> mdlLst) {
        super(context, R.layout.adpt_searchfilter_category, mdlLst);
        this.context = context;
        this.mdlLst = mdlLst;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        protected CheckBox chkBxCatId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_searchfilter_category, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.chkBxCatId = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBxCatId);
            viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                            mdlLst.get(getPosition).setCheckboxState(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                        }
                    });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setTag(position); // This line is important.
        viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setText(mdlLst.get(position).getCategoryName());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: how the return value of isSelected() is initialized ?

Comment: A tip for you... always set onClickListener on checkbox or radio button and inside that check if it is checked or not.....bcz onCheckedChanged is called several times and may create confusion.

Comment: @Blackbelt ... Sry i had posted wrong code .... see the edit ...i have pasted right code :)

Comment: it's due of the recycling mechanism of ListView. What are you experiencing is the correct behaviour

Comment: @Blackbelt .... How can i correct myself

Comment: you need the setChecked line in getView: `viewHolder.chkBxCatId.setChecked(mdlLst.get(position). isSelected())` should do it

Comment: Cool ! . i undertand musch clear about recycling... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state of the check box copied to others view because the adapter is reusing the convertview.

1. I suggest adding an `isChecked` variable to the `Model` object.
2. In the "get view" method, you should use this:

   ```
   viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isChecked);
   ```
3. Don't use `setOnCheckedChangeListener`, because this:

   ```
   viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isChecked);
   ```

   will invoke the method onCheckedChanged.
4. Implement OnClickListener on `viewHolder.checkbox`, and when you get the click event just switch the boolean state (using `Model.isChecked = !Model.isChecked`) and then `notifyDataSetChanged`.